# Displaying the Tor circuit via terminal

Tags: circuit, linux, debian

I'm using Debian 7 server. I will try to use proxychains. Is it possible to see the current Tor circuit (IP addresses) via terminal?

Answer (score 1):

To get circuit information you'll [need a ControlPort](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html). Here's a couple example scripts that provide circuit information...

- [Script to list current circuits](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/examples/list_circuits.html)
- [Script to show information about exit relays you use](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/examples/exit_used.html)